# Fourier series or Fourier transform for approximating data

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, fourier-transform, data-analysis

My goal is to approximate some data given in this form of $$\{x_i, y_i\}_{i=1,..,n}$$

where $x_i$'s are the inputs and $y_i$'s are the outputs. To approximate this function, I want to do this in a "lower dimensional space". Thus I was thinking of using Fourier Series.

My idea was to:

- Consider the process describing the data as having an underlying function plus some noise $f(x) + \epsilon$.
- Imagine that this function is periodic in $\left(x_{min} = \min\limits_{i}\{x_i\}, x_{max} = \max\limits_{i}\{x_i\}\right)$.
- Use a cosine  (or sine) fourier series and fit it to the data, obtain the coefficients of a truncated Fourier Series. At this point if I have $k$ coefficients with $k<n$, I have fewer dimensions.

However, I often hear about using fourier transform instead. I had a look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/264258/fourier-transform-vs-fourier-series) and at the definition of it in wikipedia ([here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform)) but I didn't really understand how we can use FT to do this.

Comment: It depends on the data you have. Why not use a least squares fit to a low degree polynomial?

Comment: The data is a time series. As time goes by, I will gather more and more data. However, what I want to do is try predicting this time series. I've tried variuos machine learning models but they didn't help, so I was suggested to lower the dimensionality by using Fourier Series. I want to fit a fourier series with k coefficients and then use these coefficients as features (or even as response!)

Comment: If your time series data is not periodic, there is no point in using Fourier series. That is why you need to know what kind of data you have, and what goal you have in "predicting". It is very complicated.

Comment: It's not periodic no. However I thought that I could consider any non-periodic function in a finite interval. Indeed I could then extend that function as periodic outside of that interval. As interval I could take the interval between the x_min which is actually t_min and x_max which is actually t_max. Thus the interval between the first observation and the last

Comment: Do you know where I could learn more about it?

Comment: Unfortunately, as I wrote earlier, it depends on the data you have. Prediction is a hard problem in general. There is an entire field of study devoted to it. You don't have a mathematics question. You have a [time series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_series) prediction question.

Comment: Well it is wind power data, I am not sure what other information you need

Answer (score 1):

> often hear about using fourier transform

I think you often hear about using **discrete** Fourier Transform for this purpose. Here is a summary of terminology,

- domain is $\mathbb{R}$: [Fourier transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform)
- domain is an interval $[a,b]$: [Fourier series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series)
- domain is a discrete set $x_0, x_1,\dots, x_{n-1}$: [discrete Fourier transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform)

Don't think that the choice of words has utmost importance here. Discrete Fourier transform is essentially the computation of a Fourier series that fits the given data points; the series happens to have finitely many nonzero terms. An important assumption is that the **x-coordinates are evenly spaced**.

Both Fourier series and DFT are best for periodic data. For non-periodic data one can use *even periodic extension* which results in the close relative of DFT called [discrete cosine transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_cosine_transform). This is almost like the cosine series, except that the most common type of DCT, called DCT-II, implements a slight shift due to even reflection being not across the first data point, but half a step beyond that.

Leaving the technicalities aside, the general idea is to take DCT, remove small coefficients, and observe that the remaining coefficients still do a decent job of representing the data. For example, I tried $x = (0,1,\dots, 9)$ and $y = (15, 16, 13, 10, 9, 10, 12, 10, 7, 4)$. The output of DCT-II, using [SciPy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.fftpack.dct.html), was $(212        ,   39.88107069,    1.1755705 ,   23.03405758,
        -12.32623792,   -5.65685425,   -1.90211303,   -2.39168326,
         -3.32623792,    1.10101934)$.

If the first number $212$ is divided by $2n$, where $n$ is the number of data points, the result is the constant term of Fourier series. The other numbers should be divided by $n$ and used as the coefficients of $\cos (\pi (x+1/2)/n)$, $\cos (2\pi (x+1/2)/n)$, etc. The shift by $1/2$ is the feature of DCT-II that I mentioned above; DCT-I does not have it but the shift turns out to be useful.

Here is the graph of the sum of $\cos (k\pi (x+1/2)/n)$ with the above coefficients: it passes through the data points, marked in red.

[image: full series]

To reduce dimensionality, we can remove all coefficients that are, say, less than 5 in absolute value. So our truncated coefficients are $(212       ,   39.88107069,    0       ,   23.03405758,
        -12.32623792,   -5.65685425,    0        ,    0        ,
          0        ,    0       )$ and the cosine series with these coefficients still represents the data fairly well, despite having half as many terms as the original one.

[image: truncated]